# Kibana - display statistics (percentage) relative to other graph results

Tags: elasticsearch, visualization, kibana, dashboard

I'm facing some difficulties displaying statistics of one graph (in percentage mode) relative to other graph results.
For example, the following graph displays the total number of write failures:

[image]

And the other graph, display the number of write failures of a specific group:

[image]

What I want to do, is displaying the second graph (Y-axis) in percentage, relative to the results of the first graph.

For example, the number of total write failures in the first graph at "2018-08-09 03:00" is 92,000 (green line).
And the number of write failures, of this specific group in the second graph at "2018-08-09 03:00" is 15,000.

So Instead of displaying 15,000 in the second graph, I want to display 16.30 percentage:

```
(15000/92000.0) * 100 = 16.30%
```

Your help is appreciated. 
Thanks.